# Prove that every matrix $\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ with determinant equal 6 can be written as $AB$, when $|B|=1$ and $A$ is the given matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> Prove or disprove:
>
> Let $A$ be the matrix:
>
> $$
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>     1 & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & 2 & 0 \\
>     0 & 0 & 3 \\
>     \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>
> Then every matrix $\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ with determinant equal to $6$ can be written as $AB$, when $|B|=1$ and $A$ is the given matrix.

My way so far:

Let $C\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ such as $|C|=6$.
Assuming $C=AB$ then $A^{-1}C=B$. And indeed $|B|=1$.

But does it prove that $C$ can be **every** real matrix with determinant equal to $6$? I mean how can I even make this $(C=AB)$ assumption, if that's what I need to prove?

Comment: Have you made an attempt at this question?

Comment: If $M=AB$, then $B=?$

Comment: @JohnDoe I have editted my attempt. Thanks.

Comment: @Ro168 Ok. You have proved the part about $|B|=1$, but have not proved that any matrix can be written as $AB$ yet. Does the second part of my answer help?

Comment: @Masacroso I thought that the notation $|B|$ literally _means_ $\det B$, no? What are you taking $|B|$ to mean here?

Comment: sorry, I misread the question. I thought that $|B|$ could mean norm of a linear operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

We have that $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$
Suppose $B$ is some matrix with $\det B=1$. Then what is $\det AB$?

Secondly, write $$C=\begin{pmatrix} c_{11}&c_{12}&c_{13}\\c_{21}&c_{22}&c_{23}\\c_{31}&c_{32}&c_{33}\end{pmatrix}$$ and try multiplying this by the matrix $A$. What does this give you? From here, how can you construct $B$?

Comment: @MorganRodgers I believe the point is (without needing to know about inverses) to see that the process of multiplying by $A$ can be undone.

Comment: @MorganRodgers As Aaron says, i meant to show that if you multiply an arbitrary matrix by $A$, then after seeing what the result is, you can go backwards and construct the required $B$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers ah yes, OP edited the question to include that stuff with $C$ after I had posted my answer. I'll edit my answer later to make that clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Too easy. Let $C\in \mathbb R^{3\times 3}$ with $\det C=6$. Then $C=AB$, where  $B=A^{-1}C$. We have $\det C=\det A\det B$, hence $\det B=1$.

Comment: Haha, it's probably a bit condescending to write "too easy". Then it becomes ironic when you don't fully answer the question either. It is required to prove that any $3\times 3$ matrix can be written in the form $AB$ for some $B$.

Comment: @JohnDoe Among this answer and yours I find this one right on the spot, while yours is cumbersome (why need to write $C$ by its elements?). Downvotes are not necessary here.

Comment: I didn't actually downvote this - maybe someone saw the question after the edit by OP, in which case it looks like you haven't added anything to the question. I'm not sure about that though. I wrote $C$ by its elements so OP can see the matrix, multiply it by $A$ and see how it changes, allowing them to go back one step and compute the $b_{ij}$'s in terms of the $c_{ij}$'s.